# Sinking Men-of-war

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I am doing the naval mission where you have to sink 2 men-of-war and board Nicholas Biddle's ship. I cannot sink the men-of-war however hard I try.

Do you guys have any tips?

Please **try** to not give any tips which requires spending a lot of money.

Comment: My advice would be to spend lots of money. You should have enough to buy all ship upgrades after sending out 10 caravans of furs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should upgrade your ship, especial with extra guns (to get greater damage), reinforced hall (to increase health of the ship) and fire bombs.

If you'll not do those things then the mission will be much harder, as the Men-of-war greatly overpower your not upgraded ship, the mission is still doable without the upgrades, but is much harder.

There are 2 possible tactics here:

- The "Head on" tactic: simply get close and bomb the sh*t of them, for this tactic, the fire bombs are a must upgrade, as they cause a lot more damage than the normal cannon balls. However, the fire bombs have a reduced range and you have to come closer to the ships, which means greater risk.
- The second tactic involves stopping the Men-of-war and then finding a nice safe spot to stand and bomb them. This requires using chain shots to shoot down the ships masts until they are unable to move and become a sitting duck. This tactic requires more time, patience and skill to execute, but is more suitable if you don't want to upgrade your ship.

As a general tip, you should practice. If you are not yet very good with avoiding damage from enemy cannon fire, navigating the ship or shooting your cannons, you should do the other naval missions, or replay previous missions, to increase your skill in high-seas warfare.